# How can I create a chrome shortcut that start with specific person?

Tags: google-chrome

Background:
I have 4 persons (Let’s say PersonX1, PersonY2, PersonZ3 and PersonW4) in my Google Chrome. I can easily switch between persons in Chrome UI, no problem.
The problem is that I have to start chrome, then switch to the person that I want to work with.

Question:
Is there any way to create four (4) Shortcuts to chrome.exe and specify the person I need to work with in the command line?
I searched and found lots of references to the “--profile-directory“ switch.  However, I am not sure the relationship between a “Profile Directory” and a “Person” in chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Before doing these steps, you have to switch to the specific user which you want to have a shortcut of.**

1. Go to Chrome Settings.
2. Scroll down to people
3. Select the user which is named "(current)".
4. Click edit.
5. Click "Add desktop shortcut".